# how to return a value from _beginthread thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am in the process of creating a two thread array summation program and i am using windows.h threads. And this is the code that i have so far.

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>     // needed for _beginthread()

void  silly( void * );   // function prototype

using namespace std;

int arraySum[100];

int main()
{
    // Our program's first thread starts in the main() function.

    printf( "Now in the main() function.\n" );


    for(int i = 0 ; i  < 100 ; i++){
        arraySum[i] = i;
    }

    // Let's now create our second thread and ask it to start
    // in the silly() function.


    _beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)1 );
    _beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)2 );

    Sleep( 100 );

    int a;
    cin >> a;

}

void  silly( void *arg )
{
    printf( "The silly() function was passed %d\n", (INT_PTR)arg ) ;
    int partialSum = 0;
    for(int i =50*((INT_PTR)arg - 1); i < 50 * ((INT_PTR)arg) ; i++){
    partialSum == arraySum[i];
    }
}
```

What i seem to find it hard to do is make the function return the partion sum to the main method. Could someone please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the address of an `int` to `silly()`, which can act as both input and output parameter, and have `silly()` populate it with the value required by the caller:

```
int silly_result_1 = 1;
int silly_result_2 = 2;

_beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)&silly_result_1 );
_beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)&silly_result_2 );

void silly( void *a_arg )
{
    int* arg = (int*) a_arg;
}
```

You need to wait for the two threads to complete.

---

Note it is necessary that the variables whose addresses are passed to `_beginthread()` exist for the lifetime of the thread. For example, the following would result in undefined behaviour:

```
void _start_my_thread()
{
    int silly_result = 2;
    _beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)&silly_result );
} /* 'silly_result' is out of scope but still used by the thread. */
```

This can be solved by dynamically allocating memory for the variable (and decide whether the main thread or the new thread is reponsible for destroying the allocated memory).

Comment: i made changes as you suggested but i receive a weird output from the following statement -> printf( "The silly() function was passed %d\n", (INT_PTR)arg ) ;

Comment: actually it doesn't receive the correct values of 1 and 2. please help.

Comment: @user581544, updated answer. Cast the argument to `silly()` to an `int*`.

Comment: hi hmjd, could you please tell me whether there a method to use a join instead of a sleep ? I searched Google but found no useful clues :(.

Comment: @user581544, you need to use `_beginthreadex()` to wait. See the example on MSDN reference page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb(v=vs.80).aspx .

Comment: thanks hmjd, but the wait method process_wait(int timeout) has a timeout parameter. And i want to wait until the thread finishes executing rather than specifying how long for it to wait. Is there a work around this ?

Comment: @user581544, yes. Pass the handle returned from `_beginthreadex()` to `WaitForSingleObject()` along with `INFINITE`. It will wait for the thread to finish.

Comment: @user581544, you need to use `_beginthreadex()`. See the example on MSDN article I linked in an earlier comment.

Comment: Is it ok to use process.h library in developing today's applications ?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot make the thread itself return something. Instead you can use a struct in your starting call.

```
_beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)1 );
```

If you change that to

```
typedef struct dataStruct {
    int ID;
    int returnValue;
};

dataStruct thread_1;
thread_1.ID = 1;
thread_1.returnValue = 0;
_beginthread( silly, 0, (void*)&thread_1 );
```

Inside your thread you then set the returnValue as needed, and can go on from there

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you might want to use futures for this:

```
#include <future>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int arraySum[100];

int partial_sum(int start)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = start; i < start + 50; ++i)
        sum += arraySum[i];
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i  < 100 ; i++)
    {
        arraySum[i] = i;
    }
    auto a = std::async([]() {return partial_sum(0);});
    auto b = std::async([]() {return partial_sum(50);});
    std::cout << a.get() + b.get() << "\n";
}
```

Maybe you want to pass a `std::launch::async` launch policy to `std::async` to enforce to create threads.